# Consolidated Maps of the same json

Tags: java, android

Hi there i have this JSON i´m mapping the "Users" with gson but i need to consolidate the maps (in this example 2 but can be more) in only 1 Map or 1 List be cause i need to send the consolidate to a Custom Adapter, as you can see i had 2 list of users and i access to each list users and atributes without problem but i need to create just 1 map or list, is there anyway to consolidate that mutivalue maps in only one?

```
[{
    "id": 999098,
    "name": "Legendary Users",
    "users": {
        "98087ffg5": {
            "Age": 20,
            "name": "dighak"
        },
        "0987499gg8": {
            "Age": 18,
            "name": "kijhg"
        },
        "1231ghty56": {
            "Age": 19,
            "name": "ramn1"
        }
    }
},
{
    "id": 999098,
    "name": "Best Users",
    "users": {
        "12312bvf123": {
            "Age": 20,
            "name": "thispa"
        },
        "50827gh65": {
            "Age": 21,
            "name": "vista1"
        }
    }
}]
```

This is my Response.class

```
public class Response {

private int id;
private String name;
private Map<String,UsersBean> users = new LinkedHashMap<>();

public int getId() {return id;}
public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}
public String getName() {return name;}
public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

public Map<String,UsersBean> getUsers() {return users;}

public void setUsers(Map<String,UsersBean> users) {this.users = users;}

public static class UsersBean {

        private int Age;
        private String name;

        public int getAge() {return Age;}
        public void setAge(int Age) {this.Age = Age;}
        public String getName() {return name;}
        public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
    }
}
```

I can access to each list of users like this

```
Response response;
response.get(0).getUsers().get("98087ffg5").getAge();
```

but i need an consolidate data of list of users with all the keys and respective values, can you help my with this?  i need to create a new class o map and use for loop? for access to all like:

```
list/map.getUsers().get("98087ffg5").getAge();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an array or arrayList of your `Response` class?

For example, setting the JSON string:

```
String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(responseArray);
```

...and getting the array of responses from it:

```
Response[] responseArray = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Response[].class);
```

Comment: i´m making a TypeList: `Type ListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Response>>() {}.getType();
response = gson.fromJson(JsonArray, ListType);`

Comment: See my edit, if that helps. If not, is `response` an array of Responses in this case?

Comment: thanks sir, but is not the problem i have, i already put the JsonArray response into the class response successfully, i just need merge thats Maps multivalues into 1.